# Games stuttering with high FPS after updating to 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games

Yesterday I decided to update my 19.04 to the newer 19.10 Ubuntu version. Everything goes perfectly fine since I burned a DVD specifically for this (Updating through software wasn't working).

I do a little bit of gaming, and while this new Ubuntu update gave me higher FPS, it has also gave me something that I can only describe as playing with 30 FPS. I've only played two games so far (Rocket League and TF2, both with native Linux support) and it's a problem since it starts giving me headaches after a few minutes of play-time. Note that on both of those games I achieve consistent 200-250 FPS. I'm also using the version 390 Nvidia's driver, and the card is a GTX 1080. This also didn't happen in the previous version I had of Ubuntu.

I'm new to this type of forums so I'm sorry if the formatting of the question isn't the best or I missed to mention something important about my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's a problem with Nvidia drivers.
After changing drivers and rebooting, Nvidia's 390 driver is the only one who seems to run a bit better, the other two (430 and 435) wouldn't even start TF2 most of the times. And although now games are at least playable, they are far from enjoyable.

Edit: Everything fine with KDE. I fixed it by resetting gnome to defaults

```
 dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

Games still appear to have a problem once in a while trying to get fullscreen, and when they don't they lag a lot. This can also be fixed (while in-game) by using

```
ALT + F2
```

and then restarting gnome-shell

```
r
```

Comment: In grub menu select Advanced Options for Ubuntu and select an older kernel. It might be faster.